# knockout - unit testing computed observables

Tags: unit-testing, knockout.js, jasmine

In knockout, i want to unit test the value of a computed observable that depends on another observable, using jasmine.

However, it doesn't work, as the value of the computed observable doesn't update when i change the other observable.

Here is my (simplified) view model:

```
function MarkersViewModel() {
    var self = this;   
    self.name = ko.observable("chad");
    self.computedName = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.name();
});
```

Here is my jasmine spec:

```
describe("string", function() {
    var view_model = new MarkersViewModel();
    view_model.name = ko.observable("joe");

    it("returns the whole array when there is no filter", function() {
        expect(view_model.computedName()).toBe("joe");
    });
});
```

When i run this, jasmine fails:

```
Expected 'chad' to be 'joe'.
```

Any idea on how i could implement that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not recreate observable, just set value:

```
describe("string", function() {
    var view_model = new MarkersViewModel();
    view_model.name("joe"); // <- here

    it("returns the whole array when there is no filter", function() {
        expect(view_model.computedName()).toBe("joe");
    });
});
```

Your computed scoped original observable (with "chad" assigned in constructor function) and used it.

Comment: I did not understand your comment below the code, but it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It may be useful to the same solution solution with QUnit :

```
test(" Test view_model.name ", function () {
    var view_model = new MarkersViewModel();
    view_model.name("joe");

    equal(view_model.computedName(), "joe");

});
```

https://github.com/thedom85/Javascript_Knockout_QUnit_Example